# Websorl returns error " unknown field 'django_ct' " when building schema.xml

Tags: django, heroku, solr, django-haystack, websolr

Our website runs with Python 3.6.5 and:

- django==1.11.20
- django-haystack==2.8.1
- certifi==0.0.8
- urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1
- pysolr==3.8.1

I generated schema.xml with django-haystack (python manage.py build_solr_schema > schema.xml) and pasted it in websolr (heroku version).

When I run below command:

```
heroku run python manage.py rebuild_index --app terradiem
```

I get the following error :

> Failed to add documents to Solr: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: ERROR: [doc=naturalearth.naturalearthmerged.12001] unknown field 'django_ct']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py", line 72, in update
>       self.conn.add(docs, commit=commit, boost=index.get_field_weights())
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 918, in add
>       overwrite=overwrite, handler=handler)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 500, in _update
>
> return self._send_request('post', path, message, {'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'})
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 412, in _send_request
>           raise SolrError(error_message % (resp.status_code, solr_message))
>       pysolr.SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: ERROR: [doc=naturalearth.naturalearthmerged.12001] unknown field 'django_ct']

I guess it is related to the following lines in schema.xml :

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
<field name="django_ct" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="django_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Any clue ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with websolr, but after changing the `schema.xml` file, you'll usually have to reload or restart the core.

Comment: did you included 'django.contrib.contenttypes' to your INSTALLED_APPS in your settings?

Comment: I reloaded the core and 'django.contrib.contenttypes was included. Error is still here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not make it work with Solr.

If it can be useful to someone else, here is how I managed to have Django & Heroku work with django-haystack:

I switched to Heroku Bonsai and ElasticSearch.

Combinations of versions were very complicated as Haystack does not yet support Elasticsearch 5.x, 6.x or 7.x, when Bonsai for multiple tenants plan only support versions 5.4.3 / 6.5.4 / 7.2.0

I therefore installed a fork of django-haystack supporting ElasticSearch 5:
https://github.com/tehamalab/django-haystack-es

And created the addon in Heroku as below:

```
heroku addons:create bonsai:staging -a terradiem --version=5.6.16
```

Everything is fine now.